# how to check if array contains an another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i need to find whether a array contains an another array or not ..

```
var array  = ['a',['b','c','d']];
```

im unable find this. so can anyone please help me out of this.

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the elements with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check if the element is an array with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```js
function containsArray(array) {
    return array.some(item => Array.isArray(item));
}

console.log(containsArray(['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]));
console.log(containsArray(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

ES5

```js
function containsArray(array) {
    return array.some(function (item) {
        return Array.isArray(item);
    });
}

console.log(containsArray(['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]));
console.log(containsArray(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Comment: thx @Nina Scholz thq for replaying.. its working fine....could you please explan it. what is 'some' & 'a' in "array.some(a => Array.isArray(a))"

Comment: it is a short version of a callback with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). the function is called for every item of the array and that item gets checked. if the check returns `true`, the iteration is stopped, because it searches for a single [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
var array  = ['a',['b','c','d']];

function contains(a, toFind) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (equalArray(a[i], toFind)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function equalArray(a, b) {
    if (a.length === b.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

alert(contains(array, ['b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't just need a `boolean (true/false)` answer, you could also use ***Array find() Method*** along with `Array.isArray()` to return the ***Inner Array*** as well. See the below example.

**EDIT**
In case you have an Array with more than one ***Inner Arrays*** then the ***Array filter() Method*** would be more appropriate.

```js
var arr = [3, 10, 18, [3, 4, 5, 8], 20];
var arr2 = [3, 10, 18, [3, 4, 5, 8], [1, 2], 20];
var arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function check(v) {
    return (Array.isArray(v))?v:false;
}
console.log(arr.find(check));
console.log(arr2.filter(check));

console.log(arr3.find(check));
console.log(arr3.filter(check));
```